# Loading device-specific iPad/iPhone UIViewController nib fails with .mm files

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nib

EDIT: where I write "class" below, I mean "the actual class name of the class", not literally "class"!

For a UIViewController in a Universal app, we use:

```
[[class alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

or

```
[[class alloc] init]; // same thing
```

with files:

1. class~ipad.xib
2. class~iphone.xib

Apple correctly loads the device-specific NIB, as per Apple docs.

But if the UIViewController has a ".mm" extension, it fails every time. Seems to only happen with Obj-C++ viewcontrollers (changing the file extension "fixes" it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, self-answering, found a workaround that works:

Instead of:

```
initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil
```

use:

```
initWithNibName:@"class" bundle:nil // where "class" == your classname, no extension
```

Whatever the bug is in Apple's code for reading NIB file based on filename ... this seems to fix it